# SQL Server - On-Insert Trigger vs. Per-Minute Job

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, triggers

My question is mainly concerned with "what's best for performance", but kinda "philosophically" speaking as well (if it makes a difference)... so let's jump right in.

[TableA].[ColumnB] stores a value that needs to exist in [TableC].[ColumnD].  Right off the bat, **no answers involving Foreign-keys** - just assume that they're "not allowed" in this environment for whatever reason.

But due to "circumstances x,y,z", [TableA].[ColumnB] sometimes gets values that do not exist in [TableC].[ColumnD], because, let's say, [TableA] gets populated from an object that exists in running code as a "serialized blob", an in-memory representation of the data, and the [ColumnB] values got populated before those values were deleted from [TableC].[ColumnD] by some other process.  ANYWAY, this is for example's sake, so don't get bogged down in the "why does this condition happen", just accept that it does.

To "fix" the problem, which method is best of these two:  1. make a Trigger that fires on-INSERT on [TableA], to Update [ColumnB] to the value that it should be (and assume I have a "mapping" of bad-to-good values).  Or, 2. run a scheduled-Job every hour/minute/whatever that runs Update queries to change all possible "bad" values to their corresponding "good" values.

To put it more generally, what's better for performance and/or what is best practice: a Trigger, or a periodic Scheduled-Job?  In context, let's say [TableA] is typically on the order of hundreds of thousands of rows, with Inserts happening 10-100 records at-a-time, as frequently as every few minutes to as rarely as a few times per day.

Comment: Thanks everybody!  Trigger it is... I'm not excited about creating one on 20+ different DBs, but, such is the life.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On-insert.

Doing triggers is like callbacks- They're more logically sound, and they spread any lag into every query. Doing continual checks (called polling or cron-jobs), you end up with more severe moments of lag every now and then. In almost all cases, using triggers/callbacks are the better way to go as having 1ms of lag added to every query is better than 100ms of lag at seemingly random intervals.

Answer (score 2):

Use of triggers is generally discouraged, but your load is light and your case seems to be a natural trigger case. Consider using instead-of trigger to avoid two operations on the same row (one insert instead of insert and update). It may be the simplest and most reliable solution (as long as you have written reliable code in the trigger that won't cause the whole operation to crash).

Since you are considering a batch job, you are not concerned with timing issues. I.e it's OK with your application that tables may be out of sync for 1 minute or even 1 hour. That's the major difference with the trigger approach, which will guarantee that tables are in sync all the time. Potential timing issues would make me uncomfortable. On the plus side, you won't be at risk of crashing the original insert operation with your trigger.

If you go this route, please consider Change Tracking feature. Change tracking will indicate which rows have been inserted since the last time you checked, so you won't have to scan the whole table for new records. Alternatively, if your TableA has an INDENITY primary or unique key, you can implement similar design without change tracking functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Triggers are both best performance and practice, as they maintain referential integrity as well as allowing the server to optimise for performance.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say what version of SQL Server you were using, but if it's 2008+, you can use [Change Data Capture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522489%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) to keep track of data changes to your "primary" table.  Then, periodically, you can run a batch over the change table and do whatever processing is required over that small set.

Comment: Looks interesting; unfortunately the servers are SQL 2005 still.  My apologies for not including that originally :)